# Tensorflow see only XLA_GPU and not GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I have  a problem  since  few  days.
I installed NVIDIA drivers and cuDNN using some step by steph  tutoriaI from the Internet. 
The installation succeded since tests on CUDA samples passed.

I then installed python 3.7, jupyter and Tensorflow-gpu.

However, Tensorflow don't see  my 2 GPUs and see only XLA_GPUs.

I tried recommandations from other posts (such us uninstalling and installing tensorflow) but this did not solve my problem.

Anyone  have an idea  how to solve this problem  ?